# mov ax,data - в чем ошибка?

Tags: ассемблер

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap: none

data segment
               string db 'CHTO TEBE NADO',0ah,'$' 
               l    dw $ - string
data ends

code segment
assume cs:code,ds:data

start:
    mov ax,data
    mov ds,ax

    lea dx,string                  
    mov ah,9
    int 21h

    mov dx,30h
    lea di,string
    mov cx,l
n:
    cmp byte ptr [di],'T'                  
    jne nn


        mov si,di
        inc si
        push di
        push cx
        inc cx
        m:
            mov al,byte ptr [si]
            mov byte ptr [di],al
            inc si
            inc di
            loop m
            pop cx
            pop di
nn:
    inc di
    loop n

    lea dx,string                      
    mov ah,9
    int 21h

    mov ah,4ch
    int 21h
code ends
end start
```

Сообщение об ошибке:
<14>:error A2004: symbol type conflict

В чем проблема?

Comment: `mov ax, @data` по идее должно быть.

Comment: @insolor , не помогает, пробовал

Comment: Как компилируете?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исходник из вопроса без изменений, компилирую так (masm32):

```
ml /c test222.asm
link16 link16 test222.obj,test222.exe,nul,nul,nul
```

Ошибок нет, при линковке предупреждение, что нет сегмента стека.

Запускаем через DOSBox:

[image: Скриншот]

Ошибку из вопроса можно получить, если пытаться скомпилировать в формат COFF:

```
ml /c /coff test222.asm
```

Результат:

```
Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 6.14.8444
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1981-1997.  All rights reserved.

 Assembling: test222.asm
test222.asm(14) : error A2004: symbol type conflict
test222.asm(53) : warning A4023: with /coff switch, leading underscore required for start address : start
```